# How do I COMPLETELY destroy an object in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Here's my repo: http://github.com/whiskers75/cyril

In bot.js, I want to completely destroy the old game object once reset() is called. How do I completely destroy an object, all its references, events, etc.. in Node.js?